# Create resource via POST specifying related field ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework, and want to allow API clients to create resources, where one attribute of the created resource is the (required) primary key of a related data structure. For example, given these models:

```
class Breed(models.Model):
    breed_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed)
```

I want to allow the caller to create a `Dog` object by specifying a `name` and a `breed_id` corresponding to the primary key of an existing `Breed`.

I'd like to use [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) in general for my APIs. This complicates things slightly because it (apparently) expects related fields to be specified by URL rather than primary key.

I've come up with the following solution, using [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), that behaves as I'd like:

```
class BreedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Breed

class DogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        read_only_fields = ('breed', )

    breed_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Breed.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['breed'] = validated_data['breed_id']
        del validated_data['breed_id']
        return Dog.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But it seems weird that I would need to do this mucking around with the overloaded `create`. Is there a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: have you seen [this QA post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/_k-cAr5j4w0) with DRF's creator himself? Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations). I am very interested in your question, so if you solve it, please post the answer. Thank you.

Comment: although I do not completely understand where your problem lies: can't you POST the standard `{"name":"rocky", "breed": "xyz/api/v1/breed/id/"}` to `"xyz/api/v1/dogs/"`?

Comment: Thanks for the QA link, @Pynchia, he makes it seem like it should be so simple ;) The code posted here does, in fact, work, it just feels wrong to have to override create for this case. I guess what I want is a `breed` attribute that serializes OUT as a hyperlink, but IN as a primary key.

Comment: May be you can create a custom related field, subclassing `HyperLinkedRelatedField`, that has a custom `.to_internal_value(self, data)` method.

Comment: thanks @dukebody I will look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [dukebody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356729/dukebody) for suggesting implementing a custom related field to allow an attribute to be serialized OUT as a hyperlink, but IN as a primary key:

```
class HybridPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):
    """Serializes out as hyperlink, in as primary key"""
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)
```

This lets me do away with the `create` override, the `read_only_fields` decorator, and the weirdness of swapping out the `breed` and `breed_id`:

```
class BreedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Breed

class DogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog

    breed = HybridPrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Breed.objects, 
                                         view_name='breed-detail')
```